# symetric encryption key exchange and storage?

Tags: c

I should design a symmetric-key encryption for sending udp packets in a self-learning network. In this network nodes don't know each other and they send a broadcast message first to find each other. (Actually every node first send a message to find where the the specific function is and then send point-to-point message to execute that function for controling). Twofish symetric algoriyhm is supposed to be used for this network. would you please recommend me the best secure key exchange and also whare and how I can store these keys securely?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sounds very much like home/course work. (There is nothing wrong with this)

Comment: nothing wrong with homework, however you should mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Two Common [Key Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange) Algorithms are:

1. Diffie-HellMan
2. RSA Key Exchange

This [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962035.aspx) should probably help you and start you on Two Common Key Exchange algorithms.

Other option is that you can consider using the [TLS Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). A fully implemented Open Source Lib [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) is available which you can use directly.